# Set of unital homomorphisms for a matrix subalgebra

Tags: functional-analysis

$\mathcal{A} = M_n(\mathcal{C})$ is an algebra of $n \times n$ matrices with entries in complex numbers, with its operator norm. Consider unital commutative subalgebra $\mathcal{B}$ generated by some matrix T and the identity matrix.
I need to determine the set of unital homomorphisms from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{C}$ in the following case:

1. $T$ is some self-adjoint matrix.
   I am not very comfortable either with self-adjoint complex-valued matrices or with the generated subalgebra. I know the definitions, but I did not work with them before.
   I know that real-valued self-adjoint matrices are symmetric matrices, and they admit the eigenvalue decomposition, which is
   $$T = VDV^{-1}$$
   where V stands for the eigenvector basis and D is diagonal, with eigenvalues on the diagonal. I found it is also true for complex self-adjoint matrices.

I am looking for a hint or a direction to go, maybe a useful theorem that I do not know of, NOT the full answer. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I would first try to consider $T$ invertible and study the one dimensional representations of $\langle T \rangle$ (the group generated by $T$). Also you might want to directly consider that $T$ is diagonal with real eigenvalues

Comment: Also if $D = \operatorname{diag} (\lambda_1,\dots,,\lambda_n)$ is diagonal, $\mathbb{C}[D] $ is particularly easy to describe

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace what is C[D]?

Comment: The algebra of polynomials in $D$ (so exactly $B$ here). Another hint: what statement can you make about the minimal polynomial of your matrix?

Comment: I have no idea what polynomials you are talking about:) but I think if my D is diagonal, I can generate $\mathcal{B}$ using matrices that have $a_{i,i}=1$ for some $i \in \{1,...,N\}$.

Comment: and zero everywhere else

Comment: If you have no idea, please study reduction before attending this problem